# Запятая перед "о чëм"

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, спп, сложное-предложение

Нужна ли запятая в данном предложении или нет?

*— Больше не знаешь(,) о чëм спросить?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***— Больше не знаешь, о чëм спросить?***

Запятая нужна. Она разделяет два простых предложения в составе сложного (сложноподчинённого).
Первое предложение главное, в нём подразумевается подлежащее ***ты***, второе – [придаточное изъяснительное](http://new.gramota.ru/biblio/readingroom/textbooks/author/litnevskaya/part5#42102), [безличное](https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F) (с одним главным членом – сказуемым, выраженным неопределённой формой глагола).